# How to create a moderate/high traffic server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and LAMP?

Tags: 16.04, server, xubuntu, lamp, php7

I am quite new to Ubuntu and have just enough knowledge of Linux. I want to setup a server running **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and LAMP(must be **PHP7**) that can handle a user portal traffic with 5000+ users using it daily. Previously I used to use Windows server with Apache or Plesk/cPanel on Linux machines with little command line knowledge.

I have few obstacles:

1 - My site (**www.example.com**) will be hosted on a separate server and I like to host the Portals on subdomain (portals.example.com) with 2 urls "**portals.example.com/category-1/**" and "**portals.example.com/category-2/**" on Ubuntu Server. I do not know how to setup "**portals.example.com/category-1/**" on Plesk without having the main domain pointing to Portals server, plesk throws an error.

2 - MySQL will be hosted on the same server.

3 - I need to create MySQL (Local and remote users), FTP users.

What is the best way for someone beginner on command line to do that

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS configured (I will have a difficult time doing this but like to learn)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + Plesk 17 (How to configure subdomains while domain points to a different Server/IP)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + Xampp 7.0.18 / PHP 7.0.18 (or 7.1.4 / PHP 7.1.4), (Is it modifiable, I needs to be moderately modified for php, apache, NGINX, MySQL, FTP)
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + GUI (With xRDP) + Xampp 7.0.18 / PHP 7.0.18 (or 7.1.4 / PHP 7.1.4)

Please bear in mind the maintainability as I am not that well educated in Linux and Ubuntu. The reason I have chosen Ubuntu is because of its huge support community. Any suggestions are welcomed.
Help or point me to articles or posts that you think it runs through step by step setup, please.